# Refreshing the android widget through code.

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created a Widget in android. By clicking that widget I am launching an activity, from there the user can choose any of the item displayed there in the list list view. I am storing the selected item in a shared preference. But the value the user have changed is not updating in the  widget until i am re installing the widget. I want to update the widget by code. Is that possible ?

Comment: From activity i want to update the widget. Widget classes and activity are in the same application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Here you can find detailed simple example including the code samples: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration